# Log4j not writing to HDFS / Log4j.properties

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, log4j, hdfs

Based on the following configuration i am expecting my log4j should write to HDFS folder (/myfolder/mysubfolder). But it's not even creating a file with the given name hadoop9.log. I tried by creating hadoop9.log manually on hdfs. Still it didn't work.

Am i missing anything in log4j.properties.?

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console,RFA,DRFA
hadoop.log.dir= /myfolder/mysubfolder
hadoop.log.file=hadoop9.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

# Null Appender
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# Rolling File Appender - cap space usage at 5gb.
#
hadoop.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

#
# TaskLog Appender
#

#Default values
hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12

log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender
log4j.appender.TLA.taskId=${hadoop.tasklog.taskid}
log4j.appender.TLA.isCleanup=${hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup}
log4j.appender.TLA.totalLogFileSize=${hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize}

log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

#
# HDFS block state change log from block manager
#
# Uncomment the following to suppress normal block state change
# messages from BlockManager in NameNode.
#log4j.logger.BlockStateChange=WARN

#
#Security appender
#
hadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}
hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth-${user.name}.audit
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# Daily Rolling Security appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.DRFAS.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

#
# hadoop configuration logging
#

# Uncomment the following line to turn off configuration deprecation warnings.
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN

#
# hdfs audit logging
#
hdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# mapred audit logging
#
mapred.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/mapred-audit.log
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=DEBUG

# Jets3t library
log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service=ERROR

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

#
# Job Summary Appender
#
# Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file :
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=INFO,JSA
#
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false

#
# Yarn ResourceManager Application Summary Log
#
# Set the ResourceManager summary log filename
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file=rm-appsummary.log
# Set the ResourceManager summary log level and appender
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
#yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=INFO,RMSUMMARY

# To enable AppSummaryLogging for the RM,
# set yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger to
# <LEVEL>,RMSUMMARY in hadoop-env.sh

# Appender for ResourceManager Application Summary Log
# Requires the following properties to be set
#    - hadoop.log.dir (Hadoop Log directory)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file (resource manager app summary log filename)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger (resource manager app summary log level and appender)

log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=false
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize=256MB
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n

# HS audit log configs
#mapreduce.hs.audit.logger=INFO,HSAUDIT
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=${mapreduce.hs.audit.logger}
#log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=false
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hs-audit.log
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# Http Server Request Logs
#log4j.logger.http.requests.namenode=INFO,namenoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-namenode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.datanode=INFO,datanoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-datanode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.resourcemanager=INFO,resourcemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-resourcemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.jobhistory=INFO,jobhistoryrequestlog
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-jobhistory-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.nodemanager=INFO,nodemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-nodemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.mapr.util.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.MapRZKBasedRMFailoverProxyProvider=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RollingFileAppender` will only write to local disk. Unless you can somehow mount your HDFS so it "looks like local disk to your OS" it won't work. You have to choose another Log4j Appender type that supports remote logging such as the [Flume Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) or roll your own.